# Python - First and last character in string must be alpha numeric, else delete

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can implement a string check, where I want to make sure that the first (&last) character of the string is alphanumeric. I am aware of the `isalnum`, but how do I use this to implement this check/substitution?

So, I have a string like so:

```
st="-jkkujkl-ghjkjhkj*"
```

and I would want back:

```
st="jkkujkl-ghjkjhkj"
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though not exactly what you want, but using str.strip should serve your purpose

```
import string

st.strip(string.punctuation)
Out[174]: 'jkkujkl-ghjkjhkj'
```

Comment: @Abhijit: Awesome! Thanks for the VERY pythonic and regex(less) answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex like shown below:

```
import re
# \W is a set of all special chars, and also include '_'
# If you have elements in the set [\W_] at start and end, replace with ''
p = re.compile(r'^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$') 
st="-jkkujkl-ghjkjhkj*"
print p.subn('', st)[0]
```

Output:
`jkkujkl-ghjkjhkj`

Edit:

If your special chars are in the set: **!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~**

@Abhijit's answer is much simpler and cleaner.

If you are not sure then this regex version is better.

Comment: I used something similar, but You can add + or * to re expression, in order to remove multiple occurrences of non-alpha chars.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thank you I'll edit the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following two expressions:

```
st = re.sub('^\W*', '', st)
st = re.sub('\W*$', '', st)
```

This will strip all non alpha chars of the beginning and the end of the string, not just the first ones.

Comment: better to use `+` though

Comment: Can You explain why?

Comment: @Fejs ^\W* will match a string 'foo', so its a wasted cycle of substitution. You can try doing `st = re.sub('^\W*', '-', st)` on a string of value `foo` and you will see a `-` at the front

Comment: Yep, just do `re.sub('\\*', '+')` *to your answer* and it is perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression.

Something like this could work;

```
\w.+?\w
```

However I'm don't know how to do a regexp match in python..

Answer (score 0):

**hint 1:** `ord()` can covert a letter to a character number

**hint 2:** alpha charterers are between `97` and `122` in `ord()`

**hint 3:** `st[0]` will return the first letter in string `st[-1]` will return the last

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer to your question may be the following:

```
def stringCheck(astring):
    firstChar = astring[0] if astring[0].isalnum() else ''
    lastChar = astring[-1] if astring[-1].isalnum() else ''
    return firstChar + astring[1:-1] + lastChar
```